# Is <supports-screens> in manifest required for tablet devices to use your app?

Tags: android

I have an app on Google Play. Users with an Asus Transformer can't find the app for some reason. My manifest is really simple:

```
<manifest 
    package="com.me.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        ... >

        <activity>
           ...
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Do I need to explicitly declare  for it to consider the app "compatible"? The Play store lists over 4k devices as compatible with my app, and all the asus tablet models appear on my end as "compatible".

Thanks

Comment: Have you added screenshots for 7inch devices in your Play Store listing?

Comment: @RED_ yes I have one screenshot for 7inch. I don't have one for 10inch. But could lack of screenshots really be the cause?

Comment: Yes, they are needed for the app to be visible. Add in a 10 inch screenshot. <supports-screens> is not needed.

Comment: Ok thanks will give it a shot and report back.

Comment: Source on images being needed?

Answer (score 0):

In one of my apps I have no screenshots for 7" or 10" tablets in Google Developer Console. I also have not declared `<supports-screens>` for any size, in my manifest. I have "Supported devices 6250" and "Excluded devices 0". I have a fairly standard app with a manifest similar to yours:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.app"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1234"
    android:versionName="1234" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            ... >
        </activity>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

In optimization tips for the app under Google Developer Console I have the following points under "Design your app for tablets":

> **Your Production APK needs to meet the following criteria:**
>
> The minimum Android version and target Android version need to support tablets (check targetSdkVersion and minSdkVersion). [Learn more](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#android-versions)
>
> Your APK should support common tablet screen sizes (LARGE and XLARGE). [Learn more](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#support-screens)
>
> Upload tablet screenshots: Upload at least one screenshot for 7-inch and 10-inch tablets to the Store Listing. [Learn more](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#google-play)

I can however confirm that my app DOES appear in Google Play for a 10" tablet running 4.2 and another 10" tablet running 4.4, without the `<supports-screens>` tag. The difference I see in our manifests is the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion. It may be that higher values of this does in fact require those options to be set as initial support for tablet was added in API level 11. If not, I would suspect there to be some other aspect of your app that makes it ineligable for Asus Transformer.